# Firefox bookmark star in address bar

Tags: firefox, bookmarks

Is there any way to customize where to save my bookmarks when I hit start in the address bar? By default bookmarks are going to Unsorted folder and I want them to go to root or somewhere else.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know about changing the defaults, but if you just click the star twice, it gives you the dialogue box for where you want to store them.

At least it does on my computer (Firefox 3.6.3 on Ubuntu 10.04).

Edit:

This has been asked before on [Mozilla's own site](http://support.mozilla.com/en-US/forum/1/553251) where it doesn't seem they have a solution.

There is [a plugin](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/7269) for being able to include the unsorted bookmarks in the menu if that helps as a workaround.

There is also [another plugin](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/3880) which may help in bookmark management (it makes single click of the star open the dialogue) but it still doesn't do exactly what you want.

Comment: Yea I know that, but the star is convenient because it's _one_click_. Otherwise I will just do it from menu. Still looking for solution...

Comment: I'm not sure you can, I've looked around the preferences menus, and also in about:config and I can't find anything about default bookmark placement. There is https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/7269 for being able to include the unsorted bookmarks in the menu if that helps as a workaround. There is also this question https://support.mozilla.com/en-US/forum/1/553251 where they basically answer you can't do it in a single click. There is also https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/3880 which may help in bookmark management (it makes single click of the star open the dialogue).

Comment: Just realised that comment should have been an answer edit, because I was adding more information that may be useful and now I don't seem to be able to edit the comment.

Comment: Thanks Dom, as it's only comment I can only upvote it... and accepted the answer